# Applying law of total expectation to iterated expecation

Tags: probability

I am working on example 9.6.1 from [Blitzstein](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmkAAGOYCTORq1wxSQqy255qLJjTNvBI/edit) (second edition, p346) (abbreviated below).

Let $X$ be the random sum of $N$ i.i.d random variables $X_j$ where $X_j$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. i.e. $X = \sum_{j=1}^N X_j$. Find $E[X]$ in terms of $\mu$, $\sigma^2$, $E[N]$ and $var(N)$.

I know there is a better solution given in the book but I wonder if the solution given below is valid? It arrives at the correct answer and I believe properly uses of the law of total expectation. My only concern is conditioning the outer-expectation on $N$ while the inner-expectation is already conditioned on $N$.

$$ E[X] = E[E[X|N]] $$
$$ = \sum_{n \in N} E[E[X|N]|N = n] P(N = n) $$
$$ = \sum_{n \in N} E[X|N=n]P(N=n) $$
$$ = \sum_{n \in N} \mu n P(N = n) $$
$$ = uE[N] $$

I tried something similar with the variance like $\text{var}(X|Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} E[X|Y=y]P(Y=y)$ which is of course entirely wrong, and this made me second guess a lot, including the expectation calculation. But, I think it is okay because in this case we are conditioning over an expectation that is not directly a conditional expectation. For example $E[X|N] = \sum_{n \in N} E[X|N=N]P(N=n)$ is similarly incorrect, because we get a r.v. equals a scalar. But I am still having trouble conceptualising this.